# SSH into LAN from outside through Airport Extreme

Tags: ssh, remote-control

I have an Airport Extreme, and a local network.

I have several computers within this network.

I want to be able to SSH into this local machine within the network, from outside it.

What I have done so far is that I open the Airport Utility program, within there I click the picture of the router and click 'edit'.
There I click 'network' and I suspect that it's 'port settings' that I should enter, so I click that. There I click 'description' and choose 'remote ssh login'. It fills several of the empty fields, I just change the one with the private ip address to the one i want to access. the default ports are 22. If I click ok on this, can I then SSH from outside? And if so, do I just do ssh <user>@<network_ip_address> -p<that port address that was given up in the airport by default>
.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three options I am aware of

#### Port Forwarding

You can set up port forwarding for *each* device you want to be be able to connect to externally.

- This assumes you know your external IP address.

For each device you could assign an arbitrary external port that forwards to that device on port 22. (Or you can do this for one device, and then connect to the others through it)

#### VPN

Were you to make a VPN with your local network, and then connect to said VPN, it would give you access to everything on on the network.

#### Reverse SSH

With reverse SSH you make use of an external server, and set up a listening ssh session. Then, on the external server you can connect to the device behind the router without being bothered by firewalls/port forwarding/etc...
This is what I prefer (as I haven't set up a VPN yet), but I have access to an external server.

You could do this with:
Device on home network `ssh -f -N -R 1234:localhost:22 remote_user@remote.server.example`

- Where `1234` is the port that remote would use forward to the device
- `remote.server.example` is the remote's address

Then, on the remote server `ssh -p 1234 -t device_user@localhost`

Comment: Port forwarding is what I wanna do. I know my external IP address. Am I basically doing that correctly?

Comment: From how I read you question, it sounds like you may have set it up correctly. Did you do this for every device (with it's own unique external port)? You may also want to use the 'DHCP Reservations' part to make sure each device will have a static ip locally.

Comment: Yes I want to specify each device that is to be reachable from the outside. Thanks for the help.